# Detect scroll direction with Ionic Framework

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using $IonicScrollDelegate to determine the users position and animate and element but I need to detect how to establish what direction the user is scrolling to animate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for late reply, but I stumbled on this while looking for an answer as well.

Firstly, a small correction: `$ionicScrollDelegate` has no capital `i`

If you have injected it correctly, you can use:

```
console.log($ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollPosition());
```

This will give you an object `Object {left: 0, top: 0, zoom: 1}`

Where `top:0` equals scrolling to the top.